# Where can I ask a question about geology or earth sciences?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where can I ask a question about geology or earth sciences on Stack Exchange?

I am looking for information about the formation of the Bushmansgat in South Africa.

Comment: Best thing you can do is go to https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid and look, go to each site and read the description, there has to be something

Comment: You've got downvotes because this isn't a very good question: you're asking for a site about earth sciences, when we _literally have a site called that_. (It's okay to miss stuff – everybody does it! We're voting on the question, not on you as a person.) [meta.se] _is_ the right place to ask questions like this, so if you're ever confused about a _trickier_ case, feel free to ask here. (Make sure to use the [tag:site-recommendation] tag.)

Comment: So when a user who is not very active on the network comes to the main help site of the network and asks an on topic question, we react by downvoting? Just because the user didn't know all the sites of the network? This person tried enough to find MSE, come here and ask. They didn't post on a random site, they didn't ask the actual question here (as we see so often) and what do we do? We downvote. Just because we know the network so well doesn't mean that everyone does. Or should. metaUser, I am sorry your perfectly on topic question is being treated this way.

Comment: @terdon the downvotes *could* be justified by quoting the tooltip: "*This question does not show any research effort*". Searching "stackexchange geology" literally brings up the requested community.

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest the Stack Exchange site called [Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Thanks to cocomac for linking to the tour page. (+1 to you for answering the obvious :))